# Decode HTML entities without semicolons in PHP

Tags: php, html, character, html-entities

Modern dialects of HTML and rules of good practice disallow to omit the semicolon in HTML entities(`&likethat;`). But I have a task to parse arbitrary pages and have to deal with the bad html entities without semicolons. And this is perfectly rendered by browsers. How can I decode HTML entities without semicolons into their respective UTF-8 equivalents with PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a list of all html entities and use this to replace all without semicolon by their UTF-8 representations:

```
// get all HTML entities
$mapping = get_html_translation_table(HTML_ENTITIES, ENT_QUOTES | ENT_HTML5, 'UTF-8');

// change array values representing the entities to regex pattern with negativ lookahead for semicolon
array_walk($mapping, function(&$value) { $value = '/'.rtrim($value, ';').'(?!;)/'; });

// replace all entities without semicolon by their utf8 representation
$html = preg_replace(array_values($mapping), array_keys($mapping), $html);
```

Comment: I have strings like `&#8211 [&#8230]`. Why this answer doesn't work for it? `html_entity_decode` works if semicolons are there: `&#8211; [&#8230;]`

Comment: it uses the result of get_html_translation_table() as a mapping list to replace html entities with their utf-8 representaions. This function returns only named html entities like  &amp; &uuml;, &dollar;, etc. but no html entities in decimal notation as you have. Since they are not in the mapping, they don't get replaced

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that you could try loading the document using [DOMDocument::loadHTML](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php), and try saving it then using [DOMDocument::saveHTML](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.savehtml.php).

You may specify additional options using [libxml constants](http://www.php.net/manual/en/libxml.constants.php).

Comment: This just escapes all `&` in these html-entities with `&amp;` instead of correctly taking them as html-entites. How should I use these libxml constants and how can it help me? HTML isn't XML, is it?